# Does fullcalendar plugin work on mobile

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to use fullcalendar plugin (http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Support/). It only support click event. Will it work on mobile with touch events/swipe gestures. Also can we make it responsive for Mobile and tabs?

Comment: It works on the mobile for me but there is no swipe functionality or any such mobile-related things

Answer (score 1):

I use it on mobile successfully.  The docs offer a couple different ways to determine rendering size, my app is responsive and it displays correctly on iphone, ipad and desktop of all sizes.  I use [jquery touch punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) to map click to touch events and it works swimmingly.  For phone size devices I like to use 'orientationchange' event: in landscape I show agendaWeek and on portrait I show agendaDay views.